# Qual è l'origine e/o la storia della frase "Non vedo l'ora" in italiano?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-origin

So che la frase "Non vedo l'ora" (traduzione letterale in inglese: "I can't see the time") è molto comune nel parlato quotidiano tra gli italiani. In inglese, è l'equivalente di "I can't wait", ma non ho mai sentito il corrispondente letterale "Non posso/riesco ad aspettare".

Comment: Due appunti: la traduzione letterale in inglese di "non vedo l'ora" è "I can't see the time/the instant". In secondo luogo "Non posso aspettare" è una frase esistente e comune in italiano, anche se meno di "non vedo l'ora".

Comment: Grazie Denis per il tuo commento. Ho cambiato la domanda un po'.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Come osservato, “Non posso aspettare” esiste in italiano, ma ha un senso diverso da “I can't wait”. Significa che non mi è possibile aspettare: per esempio, succede qualcosa fra un'ora, ma io devo andare via entro mezz'ora.

Comment: "Non vedo l'ora" non ha come equivalente solo "*I can't wait*" ma anche "*I'm looking forward to*", che suggerisce la stessa idea di guardare verso il futuro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il seguente [estratto](http://pietromaccallini.blogspot.com/2018/04/non-veder-lora.html) cerca di analizzare l’origine dal verbo “vedere” dal latino vid-ere (vedere) con il senso si “aspettare, attendere” da cui probabilmente la nostra espressione  “non vedo l’ora”.

> …… il significato originario che a me sembra il più probabile è: ***non posso attendere l’ora…*** nel senso di non sapere, non riuscire ad aspettare, tanto sono impaziente, l’ora in cui avverrà l’evento così desiderato.
>
> Abbiamo visto infatti che la radice di lat. vid-ere ‘vedere, guardare’
> poteva benissimo, nei primordi della sua storia, avere il significato
> di ‘aspettare, attendere’ come altri verbi esaminati, relativi
> all’area del senso della vista.
>
> Sappiamo poi che il latino era una lingua concreta e diretta, per cui essa faceva solitamente a meno dei
> numerosi verbi cosiddetti fraseologici e spesso riempitivi come
> appunto sapere, potere, riuscire, volere, che in italiano si
> accompagnano di frequente agli infiniti di altri verbi per
> specificarne il colore.   Perciò  il semplice non video horam ‘non
> vedo l’ora’ si può rendere in italiano con ‘non riesco (non posso, non
> so, ecc.) a vedere l’ora…

(pietromaccallini.blogspot.com)

Comment: E chi è Pietro Maccallini?

Comment: Molto interessante. Grazie per questa spiegazione. Sembra che la maggior parte delle parole italiane vengono da latino perché è la lingua più vicina al latino.

Comment: @compbiostats: Attento: quell'estratto viene da un blog di chissà chi, che per giunta si esprime in termini di “a me sembra” e fa considerazioni generali che vogliono dire tutto e niente (“il latino era una lingua concreta e diretta...”). Non lo prenderei come una fonte definitiva.

Comment: Hai ragione DaG... era solo per la mia curiosità... Non sappiamo ancora chi è Pietro Maccallini.